# c unix execl not working with string built with strcat

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to run execl with a pathname built with command line arguments. It was not working so i hardcoded the strings being concatenated so it still did not work. If i supply a char *path = "some path name" and pass it to execl, it works correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
//set char path name
 char pathname[256];
 strcat(pathname,"/bin/");
 strcat(pathname,"ls"); //"ls" will be replaced with arg[1]
 int pid=fork();
  if (pid==0){
     execl(pathname,"ls",(char *)0);
  }
  else{
  wait((int*)0);
  }
return 0;
}
```

I've printed out pathname to make sure it is "/bin/ls" which it is.

Comment: Change the first `strcat` to `strcpy`; does it work now?  If not, insert an unconditional call to `perror(pathname)` immediately after the `execl`.  (The `exec*` functions only return if they fail.)  Also, just on general principles, this program needs `#include <unistd.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>`.

Comment: Also also, you say you printed out the pathname to make sure it was `/bin/ls`, but did you make certain there were no invisible characters?  With my suggested modifications, `./a.out 2>&1 | cat -v` should tell you.

Comment: changing the first strcat to strcpy worked! What difference did this make? Was the first method adding something in the beginning that was visible when i printed the pathname?

Comment: Automatic variables are not implicitly initialized. Therefore `pathname` starts containing garbage to which you append `/bin/ls`. This is Undefined Behavior. The program could have just as easily crashed or done some other strange behavior. You could also have changed the definition to `char pathname[256]="";` and left the `strcat`.

Comment: @JohnnyBoy: you need a valid string before you can `strcat()` to it, and `char pathname[256]` doesn't give you one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char pathname[256];
strcat(pathname,"/bin/");
```

You did not initialize `pathname`.  Therefore, its contents are "indeterminate" and the call to `strcat` has what is officially known as Undefined Behavior -- it is allowed to do literally *anything*.  The concrete thing that probably happened was, there was some binary garbage in the memory space allocated to `pathname`, and `strcat` cheerfully treated that as a string, so the contents of `pathname` after both `strcat` calls were something like (hexadecimal)

```
01 02 03 2f 62 69 63 2f 6c 73 00
```

When you printed out the string, those leading control characters were not visible, but when you called `execl` the kernel cheerfully accepted the request to execute a file named `"\001\002\003/bin/ls"` (relative to the current working directory, of course), and since there is no such file, failed and set `errno` to `ENOENT`.  With `perror(pathname)` immediately after the `execl` and the program invoked with `./a.out 2>&1 | cat -v` you would have seen something like

```
^A^B^C/bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

Changing the first `strcat` to `strcpy` corrects this problem because `strcpy` always copies to the beginning of its destination buffer, ignoring whatever was there beforehand; once that's done, the bytes of `buf` up to and including the first NUL are determinate and `strcat` has well-defined behavior ...

... however, if you change your program back to reading the thing to copy after `/bin/` from `argv[1]`, and the first command-line argument is more than 250 bytes long, bang, you have undefined behavior again.  The *better* way to write this program is using [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s program\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    char *pathname;
    if (asprintf(&pathname, "/bin/%s", argv[1]) == -1) {
        perror("asprintf");
        return 1;
    }

    execl(pathname, argv[1], (char *)0);
    perror(pathname);
    return 127;
}
```

(If you don't have `asprintf` it is straightforward to roll it yourself using `snprintf` and `malloc`.  If you don't have `snprintf` get a real computer.)